# Get column names in subquery, and then return values for those columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, subquery

Seems like this is impossible, but I'm so close - maybe someone can take me the last step...

I have a bunch of dynamic code and I don't always know the tables and columns I'm going to be dealing with, but I do know that VARCHAR2 columns with data_lengths of 2000 result in errors. I'd love to be able to identify these 'bad' columns dynamically, and remove them from my results in 1 shot.

This code:

`SELECT LISTAGG(probs.column_name, ', ') 
    WITHIN GROUP  (ORDER BY column_name) FROM
        (select 1 grp, column_name 
        from all_tab_columns 
        where TABLE_NAME = 'MYTABLE' AND 
        DATA_TYPE <> 'VARCHAR2' AND 
        DATA_LENGTH < 2000
        ) probs 
    GROUP BY GRP`

Gives me a nice comma, separated list of all of my acceptable column names like this:

`FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4...`

And I am hopeful that there's a way a can simply do something  to drop that list of field names into a select statement like this:

`SELECT (<my subquery, above>)
    FROM MYTABLE;`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this situation

```
create table mytable ( a number, b number, c number)
insert into mytable values (10, 20, 30)
insert into mytable values (1, 2, 3)
```

and that only exists one table with that name (otherwise you should specify the owner in the query from `all_tab_columns`), your query could be simplified this way:

```
SELECT 'select ' || LISTAGG(column_name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name) || ' from ' || table_name
    FROM all_tab_columns
   WHERE     TABLE_NAME = 'MYTABLE'
         AND DATA_TYPE <> 'VARCHAR2'
         AND DATA_LENGTH < 2000
GROUP BY table_name
```

this would give: `select A, B, C from MYTABLE`.

The problem here is that you can not simply run a statement that returns a variable number of columns; one way to use this could be building an xml:

```
SELECT xmltype(
               DBMS_XMLGEN.getxml(
                                  (  SELECT 'select ' || LISTAGG(column_name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name) || ' from ' || table_name
                                       FROM all_tab_columns
                                      WHERE     TABLE_NAME = 'MYTABLE'
                                            AND DATA_TYPE <> 'VARCHAR2'
                                            AND DATA_LENGTH < 2000
                                   GROUP BY table_name)
                                 )
              )
  FROM DUAL

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
  <ROW>
    <A>10</A>
    <B>20</B>
    <C>30</C>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <A>1</A>
    <B>2</B>
    <C>3</C>
  </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

Another way could be using some PLSQL and dynamic SQL, with a little modification of yur query to concatenate the fields, to build the result in a unique string:

```
declare
    type tTabResults is table of varchar2(1000);
    vSQL varchar2(1000);
    vTabResults tTabResults;
begin
    SELECT 'select ' || LISTAGG( column_name, '|| '', '' ||') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name) || ' from ' || table_name
    into vSQL
        FROM all_tab_columns
       WHERE     TABLE_NAME = 'MYTABLE'
             AND DATA_TYPE <> 'VARCHAR2'
             AND DATA_LENGTH < 2000
    GROUP BY table_name;
    --
    execute immediate vSQL bulk collect into vTabResults;
    --
    for i in vTabResults.first .. vTabResults.last loop
        dbms_output.put_line(vTabResults(i));
    end loop;
end;



10, 20, 30
1, 2, 3
```

Notice that I oversimplified the problem, treating numbers as strings and not using any conversion, by simply printing the values in your table, no matter their type; in a real solution you should handle the possible types of your columns and modify the initial query to add some type conversions.

Comment: Thanks Aleksej - It's definitely not as simple as I hoped, and since my dynamic code was all in R (which I'm more facile with), I ended up doing 2 queries - the first to identify all of the varchar2 fields, and then used R to handle them, and build an appropriate final query.  I really appreciate your time - thanks!